# Borderlands2- Does UVHM have the last main mission from TVHM and NVHM?

Tags: borderlands-2

Ive finished TVHM in Borderlands 2 but then later on, I heard That you have a very high chance to get one of the legendaries that the Warrior drops when killing him when having the final main mission on, allowing me to farm him with a higher chance of finding a legendary.

So I was wondering if it is possible to find that mission in UVHM to get the high legendary percentage or was TVHM my last chance to farm that way without starting a new character?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your title question, Yes, UVHM is the same story again. In the same way TVHM was.

The only real differences are the difficulty and the loot. For the details on these changes take a look at the [wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Mode)

In answer to you question in the actual question body: All drops have a higher chance of being legendary (or Pearlescent) in UVHM. So yes you can farm the warrior on UVHM (But bare in mind, it will be incredibly difficult compared to TVHM)